# how to use Actionbar.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled on older APIs

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-actionbar-compat

I used this xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true">
     ...
     ...

</ScrollView>
```

And in activity:

```
ActionBar myActionBar;
myActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
myActionBar.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled(true);
```

It worked on android 5 , i want to use it on older APIs , but nestedScrollingEnabled is only supported on API 21.
I'm sure this should work on older APIs , because most google apps use this feature.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nestedScrollingEnabled` is used to permit child views to scroll within the parent.

Depends if you have more scrolling children within your `ScrollView`, hence, the need of `nestedScrollingEnabled`.

If you have only one `ScrollView`, hiding the `ActionBar` should be done on amount of collected `dy` in the scrolling callback. That's basically what does `setHideOnContentScrolled()` does. Either you offset/translate your `Toolbar` (if you are using Toolbar as Actionbar) by some amount on Y-axis or just call .hide() on the ActionBar. This should work on all versions.